# Кнопка не ловит событие .click() вызванное в ручную

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
timer = setInterval(function() {
    // Получаем список всех текущих бизнесов
    let biz_list = document.querySelectorAll('.one-business');

    for (let i = 0; i < biz_list.length; ++i) {
        // Получаем название текущего бизнеса
        let biz = biz_list[i].querySelector('div[class*="item--"]');
        let biz_name = biz.className.split(' ')[1];
        // Если бизнес нужный, тыкаем на кнопочку захвата
        if (biz_name === biz_id) {
            // Кнопка захвата
            biz_list[i].querySelector('.lobby-item__button').click();
            // Кнопка подтверждения захвата
            document.querySelector('.btn.small-btn.green').click();
            // Если лобби создалось завершаем скрипт
            if (biz_list[i].querySelector('.usersForAttack')) {
                stop_scan();
                add_message('Ловля бизнеса прекращена, лобби создано');
            }
        }
    }

}, 500);
```

Есть такой код который должен нажимать нужную кнопку, в моём случае она выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код для совершения нажатия успешно срабатывает без каких либо ошибок:

`biz_list[i].querySelector('.lobby-item__button').click();`

Но сама кнопка никак не реагирует на нажатие, (не высвечивается окно с подтверждением, как это бывает когда нажимаешь в ручную), если же нажать на кнопку самостоятельно (мышкой) все прекрасно тригерится, с чем это может быть связано? Есть информация что движок сайта `React`

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй тригерить ивент нажатия

```
business[i].querySelector('.lobby-item__button').dispatchEvent(new Event('click'))
```

Comment: Не, результат true, но кнопке по-прежнему по барабану)